# mysql slow log file: turn off binary columns

Tags: mysql

I have enabled MySQL's slow logging functionality. The problem is: the slow-log file is rapidly growing in size causing the disk to frequently run out of space.
Here is a sample slow log entries

```
# Time: 2022-02-01T15:15:17.295538Z
# User@Host: libadmin[myhost] @ data9384.library.ext.rx  Id: 5263221
# Schema: chicago  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 3.279673  Lock_time: 1.872031  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1  Rows_affected: 1
# Bytes_sent: 52
SET timestamp=1643728517;
UPDATE /* acl8574.example.com */ books SET createdon=113256972, deletedon=NULL, updatedon=1772928497, options=0, permissions='!\"¥±ñr“\\aS\Ó2,²', data='tá©†À\â‚!.....<50MB more>   WHERE id=38028274659201
# Time: 2022-02-01T15:18:10.134873Z
# User@Host: libadmin[myhost] @ data0038.library.ext.rx  Id: 5263248
# Schema: miami  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 1.363156  Lock_time: 0.000015  Rows_sent: 371816  Rows_examined: 743632  Rows_affected: 0
# Bytes_sent: 18963208
SET timestamp=1643728690;
SELECT id, title, publicationdate, catalogue FROM categories WHERE .....;
```

The number of slow statements is minimal but some of the stmts logged are UPDATEs/INSERTs. These stmts are updating/inserting into tables defined with very large binary columns. The binary data is being logged inside the slow log file (in the example above, please refer to the **data** column in the UPDATE stmt). These binaries are frequently +50MBs, thus causing the slow log file to explode in size quickly.

Is there a way to turn off the logging of binary columns in MySQL? For instance, in the example above, I want to NOT log the **data** column, ie, not log any binary column if possible.

Please note, this question is not able perusing the slow log file by filtering out the binary data. I am already able to do so. My sole objective is not to have the slow log file rotation overrun the disk which is currently happening even after compressing the rotated files.

Comment: [Doesn't appear to be](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html#slow-query-log-parameters). Adjust url for exact server major version.

Comment: What do you want?  Characters instead of binary?  That would shrink things by less than 2x.

Comment: What is the big Blob column?  Maybe it should not be in the table.

Comment: Rotate more frequently?

Comment: Thanks @danblack, it doesn't seem to have an inherent feature in mysql. I feel we're not the only outfit who's facing this problem! We can develop a makeshift workaround by piping the slow-log output to gawk and filtering out the unnecessary binary data but this solution seems cumbersome.

Comment: Use `pt-query-digest` in the logrotation for even more compression. I'm sure someone has done that. I haven't, but it be kinda cool and useful as a summary. I'm hoping this abbreviates the columns too.